# Input/output error while using google colab with google drive

Tags: machine-learning, google-colaboratory

When I use google colab I get this error more than once and randomly Sometimes it works and sometimes not

```
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

is this error occur when I interface with google drive ? 
any solutions for this bug

Answer (score 14):

From [the FAQ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html) --

> Google Drive operations can time out when the number of files or
>   subfolders in a folder grows too large. If thousands of items are
>   directly contained in the top-level "My Drive" folder then mounting
>   the drive will likely time out. Repeated attempts may eventually
>   succeed as failed attempts cache partial state locally before timing
>   out. If you encounter this problem, try moving files and folders
>   directly contained in "My Drive" into sub-folders. A similar problem
>   can occur when reading from other folders after a
>   successfuldrive.mount(). Accessing items in any folder containing many
>   items can cause errors like OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
>   (python 3) or IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error (python 2). Again,
>   you can fix this problem by moving directly contained items into
>   sub-folders.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error while using os.listdir on a google drive folder that had over 5.5k files in it, and a little window in the bottom left corner of my colab notebook popped up saying a timeout had occurred.

**Because I have Colab Pro, I tried switching my runtime Hardware Accelerator to a GPU and Runtime Shape to High-Ram. This fixed the problem for me. It might have been one or both of those options together, not sure.**

The problem with the top answer is that you might need some simple functionality in Colab (like os.listdir) in order to efficiently move files and create sub-folders to achieve reduced folder contents. If you can't even list what's in a folder without a timeout error occurring, you may just need to upgrade to Colab Pro to gain those advanced runtime options for a more powerful computing environment.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution would be to save your files in a different (new folder) directory. I think @bob-smith's solution is one the best solutions for this problem, I am just showing a variation of the original solution which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I face it almost regularly along with a dialogue-

> A Google Drive timeout has occurred (most recently at 12:46:20 PM). More info.

Sometimes if I run a code cell *three times*, the error doesn't occur anymore; sometimes I have to run the cell as much as *8-9 times* to successfully execute it.

*The problem always happens during the data loading*, as expected. In the data loading cell, I usually have splitting, item transforms, and batch transforms defined. So they add extra time cost when running the cell multiple times.

What I do instead of running the data loading cell multiple times, I run an `ls` command on Bash using the `!` method in a different cell. I usually look for a file (with a known file name) in the training directory and pass that pattern to a `grep` piped to the `ls`. Like so-

```sh
! ls /content/path/to/training/dr/ | grep xyz_001 # I *know* xyz_001 exists in a filename
```

If this cell executes successfully after n number of tries, **and** shows the desired filename in the output, the data loading cell runs successfully 100% of the time, and you can begin the training.

It is important to note that I am not running a `ls` with the entire training directory without a `grep` because that will always fail as my training directory sometimes have about 100k files.

This is an ugly hack but it works every time.