# Input/output error when trying to copy files from Google Drive to Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colab the past few months w/o any problem. However, today and out of the blue, running the command

```
!cp 'drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/data/nofilter/tonsils_nofilter1_val.pytable' .
```

gives back the error

```
cp: error reading 'drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/data/nofilter/tonsils_nofilter1_val.pytable': Input/output error
```

The file for which the error is raised is ~2-3GB and in the past I have been copying this and other larger files w/o any problem.

Today though, smaller files can be copied but this one and larger or similar ones cannot be copied.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973331/input-output-error-while-using-google-colab-with-google-drive), and I deleted a bunch of files and folders in my Google Drive to no avail.

Please advise. Thanks.