# OpenCV imread and imwrite too slow on Google Drive using CoLab

Tags: python, image, opencv, google-colaboratory, drive

I'm using Google CoLab and running a snippet of code that iterates over 170K-190K images, reads them from a path like **gdrive/My Drive/folder1/img.jpg** using `cv2.imread` function, then resizes them using `cv2.resize` function, then writes them in a path like **gdrive/My Drive/folder2/img.jpg** using `cv2.imwrite`.

But it is WAY TOO SLOW. I used to run in on my device using Jupyter Notebook, on Linux Ubuntu LTS18.04 OS, and it iterated fast. Now, each iteration takes near 30 seconds, which will estimate that the code will take near 65 days?!

What is causing it to be that slow on CoLab and how can I make it faster?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the problem of OpenCV, but of Google Drive. Accessing files from Google Drive is very slow even though you perform in Google Colaboratory.

> One better way is to copy the files into your Colab storage, then you
> will get faster performance which will be based on runtime
> (CPU/GPU/TPU) you are using.

To copy files, you can use shutil library ([Shutil documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)):

```
import shutil

# To copy files
shutil.copyfile('source_file_location', 'destination_file_location')

# To copy multiple files of folder with some conditions
import os
for file in os.listdir('folder_path'):
    if file.endswith('.jpg'):
        shutil.copyfile('folder_path' + file, 'desination_folder_path' + file)

# To copy folders
shutil.copytree('source_path', 'destination_path')
```

Since you have many in a single folder on Google Drive, accessing all the files may fail (sometimes). It's a good practice to keep files in batches in many folder (it will eliminate some errors while using Google Drive through Colab). [See more about this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973331/input-output-error-while-using-google-colab-with-google-drive)

Comment: How do I copy files into my CoLab Storage? I don't get which you mean.

Comment: hover on 'RAM, Disk' on top right, it will show the disk space

Answer (score 0):

The reason for so is the overhead of paths and reading from the Drive.

I found the best way to make it faster, is have the files I am reading on CoLab storage itself.

There is two ways to do so, one is to copy the files using Linux commands in CoLab environment, from the drive to the main directory of storage. Something like `!cp <source directory> <destination directory>`

For example, in our case: `!cp "gdrive/My Drive/datasets/imdb_crop" "imdb_crop"`.

Other way, in case the data you have is compressed, to save the decompressing time, decompress it directly into CoLab storage.

If using tar file:

```
from google.colab import drive
import tarfile
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
fname = 'gdrive/My Drive/IMDB_Dataset.tar'
tar = tarfile.open(fname, "r:")
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

If using zip file:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

import zipfile
filename = "drive/My Drive/IMDB_Dataset.zip"
with zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'r') as zipp:
zipp.extractall()
zipp.close()
```

To make sure it worked, you would find in the files of the CoLab environemnt--which you can see from the side tabe--that there is folder imdb_crop (for example) in the main directory, outside of gdrive.

When I read files then directly from imdb_crop folder, it was much faster.